# When dockerizing a rails app with EC2 container service with ELB do I still need nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker

I have a container with a **rails app** and **puma** app server, listening on port `3000`.

This container is to be deployed to amazons [ec2 container service (ECS)](https://aws.amazon.com/de/ecs/), and should be autoscaled and load balanced via [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/de/elasticloadbalancing/).

How does **nginx** (if at all) fit into the picture? Do I still need it?

If yes, should I package it inside the rails container, or should I create and deploy a seperate container instance packaged with nginx, which then provides reverse proxy functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nginx is a reverse proxy that's great at handling stuff upstream of your Rails app. Examples include preventing garbage requests getting to your Rails app in the first place and serving static assets. It's almost never a good idea to serve an app in production without a reverse proxy like Nginx in front of it. Most importantly for your question, this is just as true on ECS as anywhere else-- ECS just runs containers and doesn't do any reverse proxying in front of them by default.

[Docker style is to have one running process per container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/). There are a number of reasons why this is a good idea that are outside of the scope of this answer, but to keep it short, this makes managing containers and letting containers know when to die simpler.

So, we know you want Nginx running in front of your Rails app, and we know you want one process per container, so it makes sense to have two containers in your case-- one with the Puma server running the Rails app, and the other with Nginx. You can then [link the two containers](http://linuxconfig.org/basic-example-on-how-to-link-docker-containers), so that they can communicate. Finally, you can have your ELB forward requests to the Nginx container, which then forwards them as necessary to your Rails app, and voila, you're done. A very similar architecture is explained in this [Amazon ECS tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html), if you're looking for more details.

Comment: thanks for the answer. My question is, wouldn't using 2 containers complicate serving static assets? would you need to mount rails directory into both?

Comment: No... not sure why you think this, so can't really give a fuller answer here. It sounds like you might have the beginning of another SO question.

Comment: it's fine, got it.

Answer (score 1):

I use puma on dev/test environment, but passenger (which I believe to be more suitable) for staging and production. And for staging/production with passenger, I don't recommend @Eli's answer.

I know the OP mentioned puma but I want to highlight the following for passenger so other reader are aware of differences.

The thing is, passenger bridges cleverly nginx + your rails app, and it wouldn't work to have them on different containers. 
Passenger/puma's job is to be able to scale a pool of rails server processes/threads depending on the incoming traffic (the idea is to have several of them running, so you're not dead when a user uploads a big file and your server has to wait for it and cannot serve other users). But passenger's magic, is to be able to start a rails server automatically based on the configuration of the nginx vhosts. And nginx is the one in charge of spawning application processes/threads through the passenger module. Thus the path to the rails application files is used in the nginx file instead of ports/proxy.

In addition, passenger provides a base docker image to work with : https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker.

To answer the OP's question, yes, you still need nginx. With passenger, the setup is to have an "app" container that includes nginx + passenger + rails server. Then for scaling, you can easily add more containers like this, under the ELB.

You'll need to tune/configure Passenger to fit your container memory (see Passenger doc)
In a nutshell you'll have to limit/fix Passenger threadPool according to the memory used by your app. For instance, one of my rails production app eats up around 250MB of memory (just for the rails process, excluding system + nginx + passenger). Previously I was running under EC2 t2.micro, and the hard reality is that I could hardly start more than 2 app processes without blowing the memory of a t2. With ECS you have the flexibility of choosing the memory/CPU for your containers.